# Find server(s) with specific event logs

Tags: powershell, event-log, windows-server

I have a task which requires me to update a windows service. This service could be under different names - it asks for the install name upon installation of the service... but the Windows Event Logs are hard-coded to a specific name in C#:

```
if (!EventLog.SourceExists("MySuperSpecialEventLog"))
    EventLog.CreateEventSource("MySuperSpecialEventLog", "MyLog");
```

How can I find all servers with events logged to this custom log?

I've been toying with Powershell:

```
clear

import-module ActiveDirectory;
$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "Windows Server*"} -Property Name | Sort-Object name | Format-Table Name; #,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack;
$servers

foreach($server in $servers){
   echo "Get-Eventlog -List -ComputerName $server"
}
```

This gives me a list of servers... then I'm trying to pull a list of Services ForEach server... then I can just filter...

But I can't seem to get the thing to click on all cylinders.

If powershell isn't the right tool - what else would work to find all servers with that specific EventLog?

Comment: your foreach should be `foreach($server in $servers)`

Comment: yeah, that was a translation error... it's the stuff in the foreach that's got me confuzzled

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? You mentioned event logs (MyLog), and event log sources (MySuperSpecialEventLog), then you say you're trying to pull a list of services from each server.

Answer (score 1):

```
$source = "MySuperSpecialEventLog"
import-module ActiveDirectory
$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "Windows Server*"} | % { $_.Name }

$servers | % {
    Try {
        $eventlog = get-eventlog -Source $source -ComputerName $_ -newest 1 -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host $_ , ":", "has $source entries" 
    } Catch {
        Write-Host $_ , ":", $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

This would echo `computer : has MySuperSpecialEventLog entries` or `computer : exceptionmessage`